# Formula Editor in Vb.NET just like Crystal reports

Tags: .net, vb.net, custom-controls

I am working on a Financial system where I have to give a capability to user to generate his own result using some predefined fields from database and performing mathematical calculations on it.

For instance, I have to calculate the Gratuity amount which equals to 10% of Basic + 15% of VDA. This formula varies from time to time and adjustable depending on certain parameters.

The entire module can be seen similar to the formula editor in crystal reports where one can select the fields from the top and add mathematical operations on it in the editor and once you are done with the formula, you have your result.

Initially, I'll have only +,-,*,/,(,),% mathematical operations.

Any idea how to get around it and how to get the mathematical result at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on my own by making a similar editor and calculated the values using dynamic sql.